Dependency grammar based dictionary
A presupposition of constructing the dependency semantic structure of a sentence is the knowledge of semantic features of all sentence's semantemes (actants, semantemes' nature as predicate or name etc; this means that we need its semantic decomposition).
Is someone aware of a dictionary of any European language (even ancient) written from a dependency point of view? (Of course I am talking about semantics mainly.)

Melchuk has been working on this for several decades (with different coauthors), see his dictionaries of Russian https://olst.ling.umontreal.ca/static/pdf/Melcuk_Zholkovsky_1984.pdf or French (in 3 volumes) https://benjamins.com/catalog/z.decfc1 A detailed description of the lexicographic principles is explained here https://www.academia.edu/23572924/Explanatory_Combinatorial_Dictionary

Then there are four volumes (so far) of Активный словарь русского языка (The active dictionary of the Russian languages) made by Apresjan and his team, e.g. https://ruslang.ru/book/aktivnyy-slovar-russkogo-yazyka-t-1-b (v. 1), https://ruslang.ru/book/aktivnyy-slovar-russkogo-yazyka-t-2-v-g (v. 2) etc. all publicly available on the official website of The V.V. Vinogradov Russian Language Institute of the Russian Academy of Sciences

On the theoretical principles behind the Active dictionary of the Russian language https://www.academia.edu/8176151/ПРОСПЕКТ_АКТИВНОГО_СЛОВАРЯ_РУССКОГО_ЯЗЫКА (caveat: it's all in Russian)

I'm not aware of anything similar done for the other languages - and not really sure if that's what you're after

@AlexB. Thank you for your broad answer. To be honest I wished for such a Mel'cuk's (or someone's like him) work on English or at least on a European language with English entries... Though I will try it!

Yeah, that'd be nice. You may want to ask Melcuk himself, maybe there's something in the works already or he knows someone who's interested in a similar project. He lives in Canada afaik https://olst.ling.umontreal.ca/static/melcuk/ Anyway, good luck!

@AlexB. Thanks again! I hope he will reply!

Jerry Hobbs and his colleagues have developed a semantic lexicon for English. Not sure it meets your criteria but it can be used with DG, there are no mismatches.
